# android parse server gradle sync fail

Tags: android, gradle, parse-platform

I am new to parse server . I just followed here "http://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/"

I added below dependency in `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.15.7'
}
```

I initialized it the `MainActivity` `Parse.initialize(this);`

it gives me an error :

> Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
>   Install Repository and sync project, 
>   Open File,
>   Show In Project Structure dialog

Did I miss something?

Any help would be appreciated ?
(android studio version : 2.3.3)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.jack.instagramclone2"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.15.7'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: There is a small button at the right of AndroidStudio, click `Sync Now`

Comment: I already tried it  (Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly.)

Comment: Did you click `Install Repository`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `SDK Manager`, update your Google repository
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but I removed android studio and reinstalled it, It worked.